# hex to int 64 signed on php

Tags: php

how convert hex A67BFE427CBDC58F to int 64 signed -6450282479763995249?

```
function bchexdec($hex) {
 if(strlen($hex) == 1) {
     return hexdec($hex);
 } else {
     $remain = substr($hex, 0, -1);
     $last = substr($hex, -1);
     $x = bcadd(bcmul(16, bchexdec($remain)), hexdec($last));
     return $x;
 }
```

bchexdec('A67BFE427CBDC58F') == 11996461593945556367.
This correct, but without sign((
how convert unsigned to signed?

PHP 5.3+; PHP_INT_SIZE == 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(bccomp($x, bcpow(2, 63)) >= 0) {
    $x = bcsub($x, bcpow(2, 64);
}
```

Comment: i use dirty hack:
if( bccomp($x, '9223372036854775808') == 1 )
$x = bcsub( $x, bcadd('9223372036854775808', '9223372036854775808') );

^__^

Comment: Hm, I think that using `bcpow` to get your constants is a bit more readable. Also, note that `9223372036854775808` should be converted to a negative value (`-9223372036854775808`), so that's why I used `>=` and not `>`.